# GenericData.Array not serlizable when run on spark

Tags: apache-spark, avro

I am using `GenericData.Array` type of **Avro format** in my method and when I run my program on *spark* it gives an error:

> GenericData.Array not serliazable .

Can you suggest how can I make it serlizable ??

Comment: I got the answer myself. To serialize it just make it java serializable by using keyword "With Serializable" . It worked for me.